# Pandas and timeseries

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have a dictionary of dataframes. I want to convert each dataframe in it to its respective timeseries. I am able to convert one nicely. But, if I do it within an iterator, it complains. Eg:

This works:

```
df = dfDict[4]
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df.set_index('start_date', inplace = True)
df.sort_index(inplace = True)
```

print df.head() works nicely.

But, this doesn't work:

```
tsDict = {}
for id, df in dfDict.iteritems():
    df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
    df.set_index('start_date', inplace = True)
    df.sort_index(inplace = True)
    tsDict[id] = df
```

It gives the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tsa.py", line 105, in <module>
    main()
  File "tsa.py", line 84, in main
    df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1997, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2004, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1350, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3290, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 1947, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12368)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12322)
KeyError: 'start_date'
```

I am unable to see the subtle problem here...

Comment: Are you sure that every dataframe within your dictionary has a `'start_date'` column?  The error seems to indicate that at least one of them doesn't.

Comment: Hmmm..let me check.

Comment: Yup. One of the entries did not have a start-date. Thanks!